# laravelで画像のアップロードをしたい

Tags: php, laravel

新規登録画面で画像を登録しようとしたところ、検証で確認し、
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)このようなエラーが発生しました。
色々と考えて調べた所、index.bladeとContollerでの受け渡しが出来ていないと思っております。
ご指摘いただけると幸いです。
また、試している最中、index.bladeでassetなどを使って指定の画像が反映されることは確認できました。
課題にある通りユーザーが新規登録画面で自由に選んで画像を入れたいと考えております。
現在の表記を共有します。追加の情報は対応します。
宜しくお願いいたします。

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h1>商品情報一覧画面</h1>

<a href="create">新規登録</a>

<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>商品画像</th>
   <th>商品名</th>
   <th>価格</th>
   <th>在庫数</th>
   <th>メーカー名</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  @foreach ($products as $products)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ $products->id }}</td>
   <td><img src="{{ asset('/storage/img'.$products->img_path)}}" width="25px"></td>
   <td>{{ $products->product_name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $products->price }}</td>
   <td>{{ $products->stock }}</td>
   <td>{{ $products->comment }}</td>
   <td><a href="" class="btn btn-primary">詳細表示</a></td>
   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">削除</button></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
 </tbody>
<table>
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\products;

class productsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $query = Products::query();
        //全件取得
        //$users = $query->get();
        //ページネーション
        $products = $query->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10);
        return view('products.index')->with('products',$products);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //createに転送
        return view('products.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $products = new Products();

        $img = $request->file('img_path');
        $path = $img->store('img','public');

        //値の登録
        $products->product_name = $request->product_name;
        $products->price = $request->price;
        $products->stock = $request->stock;
        $products->img_path = $request->img_path;
        //保存
        $products->save();

        //一覧にリダイレクト
        return redirect('products');
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

```
  @foreach ($products as $products)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ $products->id }}</td>
   <td><img src="{{ asset('/storage/img'.$products->img_path)}}" width="25px"></td>
   <td>{{ $products->product_name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $products->price }}</td>
   <td>{{ $products->stock }}</td>
   <td>{{ $products->comment }}</td>
   <td><a href="" class="btn btn-primary">詳細表示</a></td>
   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">削除</button></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

上記のforeachで`$products as $products`の箇所を`$products as $product`に修正し、内部の変数名を修正してみてください。

```
  @foreach ($products as $product)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
   <td><img src="{{ asset('/storage/img'.$product->img_path)}}" width="25px"></td>
   <td>{{ $product->product_name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
   <td>{{ $product->stock }}</td>
   <td>{{ $product->comment }}</td>
   <td><a href="" class="btn btn-primary">詳細表示</a></td>
   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">削除</button></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: ご教示いただきありがとうございます。
無事画像反映できました。